# Evaluate Unix Variable with multiple parts

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

How can I do the following in Unix:

1) Variable xxx_yyy=12345
2) Variable aaa=yyy

How can I evaluate xxx_$aaa to give me 12345.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash (and probably others: specify if you want another), use `eval`. Don't forget to escape the first `$` as shown:

```
eval echo \$xxx_$aaa
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash use [indirect parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
varname=xxx_$aaa
echo ${!varname}
```

However, dynamic variable names are usually tricky to handle. Easier to use an associative array:

```
declare -A xxx
xxx[yyy]=12345
aaa=yyy
echo ${xxx[$aaa]}
```